# Autodesk Forge "View BIM 360 & Fusion models" sample

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm just starting with Autodesk Forge, and I'm trying to follow "View BIM 360 & Fusion models" sample on https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels.

The tree correctly shows the hubs, projects, files and versions.

However, when I pick some version the viewer don't show that file.

I also tried to download directly from GitHub (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/tree/net), but same thing happens...

Tried with .rvt and .pdf.

Any kind of configuration that I'm missing?

** Update **:

I've debug the code and found:

- DataManagementController -> GetItemVersions gets urn value;
- for that versions, launchViewer(urn, viewableId) gets "Error: 403 (Unauthorized)"
- viewableId is undefined

I am looking at .rvt and .pdf files...

I am missing any configuration? Any clue?

Regards
António

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The Viewer needs access to Model Derivative API.
Ensure it is properly configured on your Forge API.

Comment: glad to know you solved it yourself !  a side note: when  the model is uploaded (no matter by UI or API) to BIM360, it will be translated automatically. So your web application can get derivative and view the model directly. While when the model is uploaded to Autodesk 360,and other 360, it will not be translated automatically. The end user has to view the model one time in UI, or you call API to translate it explicitly.